# Multiple X sessions under KDE Plasma

Tags: debian, tty, kde-plasma, xorg

I'm standardising an installation of a debian machine with KDE Plasma as the desktop environment.
On this machine, there must be 2 sessions always open, one administrator and one user.
When the machine starts up, I'd like the user session to be on TTY 7 and the administrator session on TTY 8.
These two sessions must be accessible with a toggle shortcut (which uses `chvt` to switch from one TTY to another).
For the moment, I have a script in the `~/.config/autostart-scripts` file for the user session which initializes the administrator session, then locks it and returns to its own TTY, in this way:

```
sudo systemd-run --property PAMName=login
            --property User=user \
            --property StandardInput=tty \
            --property TTYPath=/dev/tty8 \
            sh -c '(sleep 10 && loginctl lock-session && chvt 7) & startx /usr/bin/startplasma-x11'
```

But the administrator session is badly initialised with many faults. It is not initialised like the user session with many configuration files not present in the .config folder, which is supposed to be generated by the system. And the Breeze theme for decorating the windows seems to be corrupted on this session (black top bar with no icons).

Is there a better way of configuring the TTY8 and making the administrator session work in the same way as the user session at startup?

I've looked into configuring Xorg's multiseat but I'm not sure that's the best solution ([Multi-Seat with Kubuntu 17.10 / Artful (systemd, sddm, KDE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1016994/multi-seat-with-kubuntu-17-10-artful-systemd-sddm-kde).
I also tried to create `getty@.service` services to configure TTY8, with no results.